# SVG Line Animation (right angle)

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to animate a line in SVG, using path. I am able to draw a line horizontally but I am not getting how to make it turn vertically at a right angle. (arrow starts from extreme left and then turns at 90 degree)

If I change the "values" in the animate section, it messes up the horizontal line as well or the animation doesn't work. I am not getting what I'm doing wrong.
I am able to achieve this using two separate SVG's i.e. one for the horizontal line and one for the vertical line, but I want to do it in one.

[Codepen link:](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzoRQw)

[Codepen link for horizontal and vertical line (separate)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjVjPM)

```html
<div>
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <marker id="arrow"orient="auto" viewBox="0 0 10 10" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="8" markerUnits="strokeWidth" refX="1" refY="5">
                <polyline points="0,0 10,5 0,10 1,5" fill="#d9272d" />
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <path id="line" marker-end="url(#arrow)" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke="#d9272d">
            <animate dur="3s" repeatCount="1" attributeName="d" values="M0,10 L10,10;M10,10 L140,10;" fill="freeze"/>
        </path>
    </svg>
</div>
```